# terminal runs python 2.7 when I have python 3.5 installed on mac.

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.5

I was installing, uninstalling and reinstalling pythons on my mac,
and I think things are screwed up a little.

At first by default, terminal ran Python 3.5 when I typed

```
$python
```

, but after doing some things, it installed 2.7 and now the terminal runs python 2.7 instead of 3.5

I installed python 3.5 form http://python.org/.

When I open up bash_profile

```
$vim ~/.bash_profile
```

This is what shows up

```
# virtualenv
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh


# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Now when I type:

```
$ python
```

This shows up:

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jun 23 2016, 17:25:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How can I reset all the python stuff(remove older versions, etc) to the factory version that i had when I first bought Mac(python3.5)?

Comment: What's the value of `$PATH`

Comment: Are you getting this within a virtualenv?

Comment: Personally I created a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` called `python3` which points to the real  python 3 binary.  I then use the `#!` line to use python3.  You contradict yourself.  First you say "*I installed python 3.5 form http://python.org/*", but at the end you say "*the factory version that i had when I first bought Mac(python3.5)*".  It is more than likely that 2.7 was installed.  3.5 and 2.7 can co-exist quite happily on OS X if you use the symbolic link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me:

**Python 3.x**

```
python3
```

**Python 2.x**

```
python
```

> in terminal

Answer (score 1):

To see what command is actually going to run when you type `python` at the prompt, check the top result of:

```
type -a python
```

This will list any aliases as well as taking into account the full `PATH` definition.  To figure out why python 2 is getting precedence over python 3, be sure to check your `~/.bashrc` file if it exists as well as your `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

To check your Python binaries, run:

```
$ which -a python python2 python3
```

Then check which `python` path comes first.

Then either set your `$PATH` or `$PYTHONPATH` (then reload your shell), or use `python2` or `python3` command instead.

You can also use following workaround:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH" ./python_script.py
```

where `/usr/bin` is pointing to the right Python binary.